# Content Security Policy contains an invalid source

Tags: laravel, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use Content Security Policy on my site, I've already done everything right, and everything works, but this error still appears in the console

> The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: 'data:frame-src'. It will be ignored.

Where did I go wrong? What's wrong here?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContentSecurityPolicy
{
    public $resources = [
        'default-src' => [
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            'cdn.jsdelivr.net',
            '*.googletagmanager.com',
            'fonts.googleapis.com',
            'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
            'fonts.gstatic.com',
            'code.jquery.com',
        ],
        'img-src' => [
            "data:",
        ],
        'frame-src' => [
            'youtube.com www.youtube.com',
        ],
    ];

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $contentSecurityPolicy = '';
        foreach ($this->resources as $key => $values) {
            $contentSecurityPolicy .= $key . ' ' . implode(' ', $values);
        }

        $response->header("Content-Security-Policy", $contentSecurityPolicy);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

There is also another error

> Refused to load the image 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net *.googletagmanager.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.comimg-src data:frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a look to the CSP you generated:

> default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net *.googletagmanager.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.**comimg-src** **data:frame-src** youtube.com [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)

but normally it should be:

> default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net *.googletagmanager.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.**com; img-src** **data:; frame-src** youtube.com [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)

You miss a semicolon `;` between directives. Change the line:

```
$contentSecurityPolicy .= $key . ' ' . implode(' ', $values);
```

to the:

```
$contentSecurityPolicy .= $key . ' ' . implode(' ', $values) .';';
```

2. `'img-src' => [ "data:", ],` means you do not load images from own site. this is an extremely rare case, so `'img-src' => [ "'self'", "data:", ],` is much better.
3. Using `default-src` as souce for implicitly init other directives is a bad practice. This can be used in simple cases, but not in yours - later you will want to get rid of the `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` directive, since its use does not protect against XSS.
   So you'll have to use `'unsafe-inline'` for `style-src` and use `'nonce-value'` for `script-src` but you failed to mix these tokens in the `default-src`.
   Also using `'nonce-value'` in the `default-src` lead to [vulnerability](http://csplite.com/csp325/#strict_CSP_default-src) in Firefox.

Distribute sources according to directives, this will save you from headaches in the future.

Comment: did like this  `$contentSecurityPolicy .= $key . ' ' . implode(' ', $values) . ';' . ' ';` and now I'm doing it right

Comment: `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net *.googletagmanager.com fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.com; img-src data:; frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com;`

Comment: But I get errores `Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:".`

Comment: (1) I have updated the answer and add `'self'` to the `img-src`. (2) Use Firefox to see what real Url hides under Chrome's `<URL>`. You have to add domain from this Url to the `img-src`. I can assume that you are using GTM, so you need [additional sources](http://csplite.com/csp/svc109/#CSP_rules) in your CSP.

Comment: I managed to solve it with `img-src`, but now, as you already said, the problem with `default-src`, like what I have there now, can be broken so that there are no problems?

Comment: Now I have this error `Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net *.googletagmanager.com `

Comment: `fonts.googleapis.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: If you use [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) you have to add `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` into `script-src`. Ignore `script-src-elem`(it's a Chrome only feature) and use `script-src` instead of.

Comment: `script-src` use  instead of `default-src` and add `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` there, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Not quite. It is necessary to move from `default-src` to `script-src` all sources related to scripts: `'self'`, `'unsafe-inline'`, `cdn.jsdelivr.net`, `*.googletagmanager.com`, `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, `code.jquery.com` and additional sources from GTM link above.

Comment: Also `style-src` should be `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;`. `font-src` should be `font-src fonts.gstatic.com;`. `default-src` should be `default-src 'self'`. During CSP debug you will add all blocked sources to the appropriate directives, but not to `default-src`.